# Pass template url to angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there any way to pass string object with template url to the directive?
My solution don't works correctly.

Javascript:

```
function moduleView() {
    return{
      restrict: 'A',
           templateUrl: function (elem, attr) {
               return attr.url;
                }
            };
        };
function ModulesCtrl($scope, ModulesService) {
    $scope.modules = [];

    $scope.run = function () {
        ModulesService.loadModules(function (items) {
            $scope.modules = items;
        });
    };

    $scope.run();
};
```

html(jade):

```
ul(ng-repeat="item in modules")
    div(module-view url="item.path")
```

item.path is a string with url o the template.

But this code don't works. i have this error:

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: item.path
```

Comment: `return attr.url;` will return the actual string `item.path`, not the url that is stored in the `path` property. You need to interpolate the string before returning it. The problem is that the `templateUrl` function runs before interpolation takes place. Also there is no `$scope` available yet, only `$rootScope`. Is item referenced from `$rootScope`?

Comment: item referenced from $scope in controller `function ModulesCtrl($scope, ModulesService) {
    $scope.modules = [];

    $scope.run = function () {
        ModulesService.loadModules(function (items) {
            $scope.modules = items;
        });
    };

    $scope.run();
};` item is element of array module `ul(ng-repeat="item in modules")`

Comment: template : "<div ng-include={{item.path}}></div>"

Comment: You will have to do it another way then. Depending on your use case, you can use what @HarishR suggested.

Comment: @Egor why are you writing directive for this? is you requirement different from what you mentioned here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this -- easiest is to use `ng-include` to include the template of the module.

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eXQ5T0imWHIjOIEA8gin?p=preview) for an example.

Ofcourse it's also possible to add a `scope` variable to an directive and let this do a `ng-include` with that variable.